# List general info about projects from project sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, metadata

I would like to be able to show general info about all our projects on a page. The page should be able to show a list with info such as project name, project description, project manager, status, etc for all our projects.

I have done similar things on document archives using content types and content query webparts and search, but I cannot find anything similar that would work on sites. If a project site could be a content type, I would have columns for those information items.

Today we have one project site per project: 
The project name is same as the site title.
The project description can be found in a content editor wp.
The name of the project manager can be found in a contact details wp.

We are using the project summary webpart, but it does not support adding any general info (same info that you also would like to display on the project web page).

Comment: Sounds like a good job for REST/JSOM surfaced through a webpart. Have you looked into that?

Comment: OK, you mean using the info in the format I already have? I guess I was more focused on updating the project site template with metadata fields, to prepare them for content search etc... I have not used REST before (only CSOM), but I googled it and it looks like an interesting API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this in almost all projects

- Create a ContentType **ProjectInfo**

  - Title
  - Owner
  - Description
- Add a List (`ProjectInformation`) to all (Project)Sites
- Fill one ListItem (`ProjectInfo`) on Project creation
- (Only Project owner may change Item)
- This info can be displayed on the Site itself
- or aggregated
- Within a SiteColection you can use the Content Query WebPart
- a Content Search WebPart is way more powerfull
- write a DisplayTemplate to present the found Items; 
  Make it a fancy UX with the [Isotope library](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

And you get:

[image]

Notes:

- The URL you get from the Item URL, we added a custom URL field as well so you can override the default URL, that makes it possible to store Multiple ProjectInfo Items in one list and have them point to other information
- Write your Control and DisplayTemplate as generic as possible so you can re-use for other ContentTypes. 
  If you put the logic for ContentType inside the DisplayTemplate you can have one DisplayTemplate for different ContentTypes.. eg. News, People , whatever
- Add more metadata:

  - Start-Date
  - End-date
  - Expired

It is a ContentType, so you can always add functionality

Comment: Nice! I have done some testing with a ProjectInfo list and it seem to work! I have added this to our project template and I will add the list to the old project sites as well, so I could use this as a method to get and to hide all non-active projects.